# React native Hide navigation bar element

Tags: javascript, react-native

i have code for a working navigation bar, however i need to hide the navigation bar, due to having a video player to when clicked fullscreen mode. the navigation bar does not hide.

Navbar.js file here is the code for the navbar

```
export default class Navbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Header
        style={{backgroundColor: Colors.navbarBackgroundColor}}
        backgroundColor={Colors.navbarBackgroundColor}
        androidStatusBarColor={Colors.statusBarColor}
        noShadow={true}
        >
        {this.props.left ? this.props.left : <Left style={{flex: 1}} />}
        <Body style={styles.body}>
          <Title style={styles.title}>{this.props.title}</Title>
        </Body>
        {this.props.right ? this.props.right : <Right style={{flex: 1}} />}
      </Header>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the file where I am using the narbar, how can i hide ?

```
import Navbar from '../component/Navbar';

onFullScreen(fullScreen) {

}


return(
  <SideMenuDrawer ref={(ref) => this._sideMenuDrawer = ref}>
//Hide this navbar
 <Navbar left={left} right={right} title={this.props.title} />
  <Container style={{backgroundColor: '#fdfdfd'}}>
  <Video url={'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4'}
  onFullScreen={status => this.onFullScreen(status)}
  style={{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width, height: 200}}/>
  </Container>
  </SideMenuDrawer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using your navbar is not a good idea always it's better to use native element's 
but by the way you should have a callback for video play and stop

```
videoWillPlay = (event) => {
    this.setState({flexSize: 0,Height:0});
};

videoWillStop = (event) => {
    this.setState({flexSize: 3.5,Height:1});
};
```

then you can set navbar height zero or if it have flex zero the flex
and you should dynamic style

```
<Navbar left={left} right={right} title={this.props.title} 
    style={{flex: this.state.flexSize}}/>
```

you can also make video play to full size and don't touch navbar

Comment: Hi unfortunately it doesnt have a callback for stop/start ::( any other way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally render a component based on a boolean. So you could introduce a boolean you toggle based on if you're in fullscreen or not, then use it to decide if you want to render the nav bar:

```
{!isFullscreen && <Navbar left={left} right={right} title={this.props.title} />}
```

In reality that might be `this.props.isFullscreen` or `this.state.isFullscreen` depending on where you want to track the value, but that's the general concept.

Here's an example using internal state based on your current code:

```
export default class YourComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isFullScreen: false
    };
  }

  onFullScreen = fullScreen => {
    this.setState({
      isFullScreen: fullScreen
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {isFullScreen} = this.state;

    return (
      <SideMenuDrawer ref={(ref) => this._sideMenuDrawer = ref}>
        {!isFullScreen && <Navbar left={left} right={right} title={this.props.title} />}

        <Container style={{ backgroundColor: '#fdfdfd' }}>
          <Video
            url={'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4'}
            onFullScreen={this.onFullScreen}
            style={{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width, height: 200 }} />
        </Container>
      </SideMenuDrawer>
    );
  }
}
```

I don't have all the info about your project, so this assumes the value passed back to `Video`'s `onFullScreen` prop is a boolean. If it's an object, you might need to use something like this instead:

```
onFullScreen = status => {
  this.setState({
    isFullScreen: status.fullScreen
  });
}
```

Comment: sorry could you give me an example on how to do that. im a little confused

Comment: Sure, can you tell me what type of object `status` from the onFullscreen callback? Is that a boolean? Object with a boolean indicating fullscreen or not? You'll need to use that most likely

Comment: Added a longer example based on the info you've given that uses internal state to manage an `isFullScreen` flag. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it didnt work, still showing the navbar. but thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Guessing your `onFullScreen` prop isn’t actually getting called. This would work if it was. Did you add that yourself? You sure it’s supported? If you could add more info about the `Video` component you created or are using that’d be helpful

Comment: hey thanks for the reply - here is the component im using: https://github.com/abbasfreestyle/react-native-af-video-player

Comment: Hmm, interesting. They even have an example in their README doing exactly what I suggested